# Unable to redirect to a url using http node proxy

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am deploying my node.js chat server on the server.Now on server the Https is enabled on port 8443 and my server runs on port 3000.Now whenever i deploy my node.js express server on the server it starts listening but whenever i try to open the page in my browser  "Segmentation Fault" is written on my dedicated Server console.I have double checked my certificates they are fine Can anyone guide me here that what would be the thing causing the issue? is that a port related issue or its a code related issue?

```
    // Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var httpProxy=require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/private/demo.iproctoring.com.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/certs/demo.iproctoring.com.cer')
};
var server = require('https').createServer(options,app,function(req,res)
{
proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'https://demo.iproctoring.com:8443' });
});
var io = require('../..')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


var numUsers = 0;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var addedUser = false;

  // when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
  socket.on('new message', function (data) {
    // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
    socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
    });
  });

  // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
  socket.on('add user', function (username) {
    if (addedUser) return;

    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = username;
    ++numUsers;
    addedUser = true;
    socket.emit('login', {
      numUsers: numUsers
    });
    // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
    socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', {
      username: socket.username,
      numUsers: numUsers
    });
  });

  // when the client emits 'typing', we broadcast it to others
  socket.on('typing', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', {
      username: socket.username
    });
  });

  // when the client emits 'stop typing', we broadcast it to others
  socket.on('stop typing', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('stop typing', {
      username: socket.username
    });
  });

  // when the user disconnects.. perform this
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    if (addedUser) {
      --numUsers;

      // echo globally that this client has left
      socket.broadcast.emit('user left', {
        username: socket.username,
        numUsers: numUsers
      });
    }
  });
});
```